# How to find the hour difference in a Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I was wondering what's wrong with my code.  It seems to be computing days instead of hour.  A little help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT email,createDate 
FROM dataTable r

WHERE DATEDIFF(hh,GETDATE(),DateAdd(hh,r.createDate, 0)) > 1
```

EDIT:
With the solution of Adam Spriggs, I was able to come up with the solution that was required of me, that is, to be able to display records with createDate in the past X hour/s. (see code below. still not perfect but works for me)  It's just difficult for me to ask the question and the only question that I could come up with is finding the hour difference.  Thanks Adam! Thanks all!

```
SELECT r.email,r.createDate

FROM dataTable r

where ((DATEDIFF(hh,GETDATE(),r.createDate)* -2 )/2) <= 1
```

Comment: You are trying to do this in SOQL in Salesforce? It doesn't have DATEDIFF function.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure if this is SOQL.  But I'm using this Query in Exact Target Marketing Cloud > Email > Query. 

Is this the right place to ask this?  Is my question relevent to this site?

Comment: @VigneshwaranG - but if you can suggest any solution without using the DATEDIFF, I would be glad to try. :)

Comment: Erwin .. you should add **Exact Target Marketing Cloud** in your question so other members can understand this question related to **Exact Target Marketing Cloud**

Comment: @sfdcweb - Thank for letting me know and adding the tag.  I will do tagging properly next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're doing a `dateadd()` function on the `createDate` column.   That appears to be the problem. You don't need it.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32e35e/1) for you to validate your query.  SFMC Query Activities run in a SQL Server environment.   If your schema on the left, matches your Data Extension, you should be able to simulate the Query Activity in the account.

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dataTable
    (email varchar(255), createDate datetime)
;

INSERT INTO dataTable
    (email, createDate)
VALUES
('test@example.com','2016-04-04 14:02'),
('test2@example.com','2016-04-02 14:02'),
('test3@example.com','2016-04-03 6:02')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
 r.email
 , r.createDate
 , DATEDIFF(hh,GETDATE(),r.createDate) diff 
FROM dataTable r
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32e35e/1/0)**:

```
|             email |              createDate | diff |
|-------------------|-------------------------|------|
|  test@example.com | April, 04 2016 14:02:00 |  -45 |
| test2@example.com | April, 02 2016 14:02:00 |  -93 |
| test3@example.com | April, 03 2016 06:02:00 |  -77 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You have definitely showed me the way. Your solution have light my way.